What is the action economy required to retrieve an item from stowage?
This question is directed mostly towards retrieving Adventuring Gear. Most of the Adventuring Gear items’ descriptions give specific action requirements to use it. However, items such as backpacks, sacks, and pouches have no action economy requirements or description for their use.
The scenario, as I imagine that would give pause to this ruling and as an example, is a character wanting to retrieve a vial of poison for application on a weapon. The use of the poison is defined as a Bonus Action (2024 PHB pg 227). However there is no action specified to retrieve it from a backpack (2024 PHB pg 224).

It‘s up to the DM to decide
The rules for Interacting with things in combat (PHB, p. 24) read in their entirety (emphasis added):

You can interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or action. For example, you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe.
If you want to interact with a second object, you need to take the Utilize action. Some magic items and other special objects always require an action to use, as stated in their descriptions.
The DM might require you to use an action for any of these activities when it needs special care or when it presents an unusual obstacle. For example, the DM might require you to take the Utilize action to open a stuck door or turn a crank to lower a drawbridge.

So by default, doing so would either be a free object interaction for your turn, or a Utilize action.
Note that the prior ruleset, the 2014 one, had a list of examples for free object interactions that included "withdraw a potion from your backpack". The new rules dropped this list, so this now is entirely up to the DM.
In addition, a round represents about 6 seconds of time in the game world (p. 23 PHB). The rules already allow you to do a lot of things on your turn in these six seconds - move up to your speed, take an action like attacking, which might translate into multiple attacks depending on your character, take a Bonus action and also a Reaction, and on top of this, take one free object interaction.
I personally would have a hard time, even without doing all those other things, in taking a backpack off my back, unbuckling or unlacing its straps, opening it, rooting around in it to search for my potion of poison that is probably buried at the bottom somewhere beneath blanket, rope, some torches, rations, among pitons and flasks of oil, grabbing it and retrieving it, all in six seconds. Never mind then closing the straps again, and re-shouldering the backpack. On the other hand, if the potion is in an open side pocket, ready to be pulled out with no need to take off the backpack, it might be a matter of only one or two seconds.
So the details of how this plays out may also depend on the level of detail or abstraction your group likes to play at. If you do not like to bother with such details, and that seems to be the default stance of the 2024 edition, which also got rid of other more realistic but less heroic rules like the variant encumbrance rule that was more fine-grained, it most likely will just be that free interaction or Utilize action. But Utilize just says “Use a nonmagical object". If that use realistically will take more than the six seconds you have, your DM might rule that one Utilize action might only achieve part of the task, such as taking off the backpack. Again, it is up to your DM.

Thanks for your detailed input, I appreciate it. In this case I am the DM and I was verifying that I wasn’t missing anything that wasn’t already presented in the PHB. I too find it hard to believe someone can root around in backpack, put it back on securely and continue to slay hobgoblins like nothing else happened.

@Bryan: Realistically, the first thing the PCs would do when they find themselves in a fight would be to drop their backpacks (if they hadn't already stashed them somewhere safe before even approaching a dangerous situation). No matter how tough you are, the last thing you want in a fight is a heavy and bulky object strapped to your back and slowing your movement. If they needed to have e.g. potions ready at hand, they'd be in belt pouch or a pocket or something designed for quick access and minimal encumbrance.

@IlmariKaronen Yes, realistically one would drop the backpack. The rules have no mechanical penalty for carrying one however (as long as you stay below weight limits), so nobody I know does that: it just costs you your first round free object interaction and saddles you with the liability of not having your backpack if you need to treat a hasty retreat. We (even with 2014) house-rule it exactly as you describe: you have to have the item in an "easy access" location to be able to retrieve it with a single object interaction. The characters often invest in special belts or straps for it.

While I agree that one has to suspend their disbelief when playing DND and must  "approximate" reality, your claim is wrong: it is not up to the DM, the rules allows to have a free object interaction and the DM my rule otherwise in some cases. Of course, this is true for _any_rule.

@Eddymage By that logic you could do anything as an action as long as it involves an object and the object has no other rules for the intended action attached to it. I don’t think this fits with the open ended nature of the ruleset, that relies on the DM to fill in the missing parts, rather than comprehensively defining all possible interactions.

No, it is specifically written in the rules what requires an action and what does not, and this can be adapted by the DM, achieving to the realism level which a table wants to play with.

@Eddymage Even if you wanted to strictly interpret it that way, retrieving a flask from a backpack would be interacting with at least 2 objects, not one - first the backpack, and secondly the flask, so it could not be achieved as a single free interaction, as the flask in the backpack is not directly accessible. I think where we diverge is in what "use a nonmagical object” covers and what not. I think whatever it covers would logically need to be possible in a round to be done as an action. And, per the basic game loop, if it isn’t, the DM will tell you so.

No no, it depends on the object! Retrieving the object from the sack is free, using that object costs per item's  description.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can interact with one object for free during your action or move.
The section Your Turn contains the following paragraph (emphases mine):

Interacting with Things. You can interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or action. For example, you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe.
If you want to interact with a second object, you need to take the Utilize action. Some magic items and other special objects always require an action to use, as stated in their descriptions.

Therefore, retrieving an object from a backpack, a pouch or sack is granted for free, since their description does not specify that you need to use your action to do so.
Nonetheless, the DM can rule otherwise depending on the situation:

The DM might require you to use an action for any of these activities when it needs special care or when it presents an unusual obstacle.


Separately from the free object interaction, you can also draw or stow 1 weapon during the Attack action: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dnd/free-rules/rules-glossary#AttackAction
